# Why does curl/wget in the ebay search box give me an access denied error?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, penetration-test, attacks, exploit

I just accidentally copypasted a wget command into the ebay search box and got the following error:

[image: ebay error]

It happens with `wget http://google.com` or `curl http://google.com`, or any other URL...

It does seem to sanitise the input and remove slashes if you just enter a URL but not if you precede it with wget or curl. What could they possibly be doing which causes a wget or curl command to bypass their sanitization and produce a different result?

Comment: "accidentally" ;)

Comment: For all the people accidentally wondering. Accidentally typing everything up to `curl http://` returns results. `curl http://` changes your search to just `curl http:` and give results and `curl http://g` gives me access denied.

Comment: Kinda reminds me of https://xkcd.com/1700/, though maybe not quite that extreme.

Comment: Curiously, with Chrome, when using Google's Data Saver extension, I could bypass `wget http://google.com`, though it got sanitized to `wget http: google.com` in the result (I know Data Saver works as a proxy, but I don't know why it "worked")

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I **assume** that ebay.com installed a Web Application Firewall, which recognizes your request as a possible attack. Therefore, your request is cancelled and you receive a `HTTP 403 - Access Denied`. The mod_security WAF for Apache, nginx and IIS behaves similar: If it is in prevention mode, it will also respond with `HTTP 403` by default [1].

Most WAFs have some kind of a rule set. They check whether your request matches one of their rules, maybe with regular expressions. I assume further that one of those rules looks like `(wget|curl) (http|https)://.*` [2]. The "sanitizing" of double forward slashes in your url happens most likely on the application level. Strings like `asdf//` will also be shortened to `asdf`.

[1] https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#secdefaultaction

[2] Skipped escaping of forward slashes for the sake of readability

Comment: for brevity, `(http|https)` and `https?` are equivalent

Comment: So what are you supposed to do if you're searching for something curly?

Comment: @JAB No problem - however, ebay has currently no articles that match `curly http://hairs.com` ;)

Comment: @cat Well, there is the difference that `https?` is greedy while `(http|https)` is not, which for this specific case makes no difference. The only reason I am nitpicking is because as soon as I looked at it I thought 'Nope, that's regex, there must be some asinine difference that can trip people'.

Comment: @Maurycy Forgive me, I thought I knew my stuff. Which inputs are matched by one of those, but not the other?

Comment: @cat none. There are contexts where it could make a difference, but this is not one of them, because (among other reasons), a colon is never an "s" so there's zero ambiguity between the two cases.

Comment: @cat If I understand it correctly, it's like the difference between `http(|s)` and `http(s|)` - which of them would be tried first.

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't make a difference here because the next part of the regex cannot possibly match an 's'. But with something like `(http|https).*`, matching against `https://example.com` will wrongly identify the protocol (the first match group) as `http` because the `.*` will match `s://example.com`. I'm sure there are also situations where one regexp takes a lot longer to match than the other.

Comment: @cat I usually use regexes for extracting out data and replacing in strings and I actually had this exact thing bite my butt specifically (ie, the order in matching group). In this specific case, `https??` = `(http|https)` and `https?` = `(https|http)`. A very specific (but unlikely) use case is stripping http and https from the beginning of the url with something like `^(http|https)` which will always leave the dangling s for https.

Comment: @Maurycy's last comment should be upvoted to at least 20.

Answer (score -6):

E-Bay is a secured service, and you are not passing the security credentials with the curl command. Most likely, you need to pass an "Authentication" header probably with either a base64 encrypted username:password combination or an OAuth bearer token.

Comment: The OP isn't actually using curl/wget to request pages from eBay. Instead, they are filling a form on the webpage in their browser with the string `"curl http://google.com"`.